# I want the number and title of document section to be a different color on the page, but remain black in the TOC - Is there a way to do this?

Tags: microsoft-word, table-of-contents

**I'm creating a word document where the title on each page will be the heading which is pulled into the TOC (1. Terms and conditions, 2. Business history, etc.). I want the number and title of each section to be a different color on the page, but remain black in the TOC - Is there a way to do this?**

When I try to update the Heading/title color to the color theme of the section, it looks fine. But when I update the TOC, all of the numbers of the sections change color both on the page and on the TOC.
Example;

1. Terms and Conditions - we want it in green
2. Business History - we want it in blue
3. Financials - We want it in yellow

When i update the TOC, all the numbers become green and the text remains the colour of the section (blue, yellow, etc.)

Comment: Have you looked at my answer? Do you need more help?

Answer (score 0):

The appearance of your TOC is controlled primarily by the TOC styles.
That of your headings should be controlled by your heading styles.

**If you apply direct formatting to your headings (not by modifying the style) that can transfer into your TOC.**

The colors of the numbers in your text should be controlled by the define mulitlevel list dialog if you are using automatic numbering. If you are not using automatic numbering, it is controlled in the heading styles.